# Drawing App in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

[image]

I am planning to develop an iOS app in which users will see a big alphabets, users can start from one place of the alphabet to the other end of it, while doing this a colour will be filled inside this alphabet. If the user correctly filled that particular colour inside that alphabet, we will be showing the next alphabet, otherwise we will show a report to the user specifying that, your drawing is not good, still needs lil bit of attention.

So i was thinking about this, I think i can draw these shapes of this alphabets by using UIBezierPath. Shapes like the image which is added above. But i don't know how to fill up colour inside this when the user starts dragging inside that path. Is there any other way to achieve this? If someone know some better way, please let me know. or give me a heads up for doing that colour filling and checking its accuracy.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I got what you want to achieve..
I have created a sample project for you, 
I hope it will help you.
here is the google drive link to that project feel free to download it.
[Drawing App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B21eezRlN5hkV0xTcnl4c3lOcHc/view?usp=sharing)

here is the result

[image]

[image]

label is updated using a delegate method, where you can do what you want